# ¿Cómo hacer un botón que cambie de frase con el autor?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

No se muestran mis frases del JSON en react, la idea es hacer un botón que cada vez que haga click cambie de frase con el autor, pero no se muestran

Este es mi componente Text, en la parte del `<li><p>{textos.frase}</p></li>` y `<li><p>{textos.autor}</p></li>`, es donde debería poner la frase y el autor aleatorio, pero por alguna razón no los muestra.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import textos from './textos.json'

textos = JSON.stringify(textos)

const getRandom = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * textos.length)


const Text = () => {

    const [texto, setTexto] = useState(textos[getRandom()])

    const changeText = () => {
        const random = getRandom()
        setTexto(textos[random])
    }

    const colors = [
        '#16a085',
        '#27ae60',
        '#2c3e50',
        '#f39c12',
        '#e74c3c',
        '#9b59b6',
        '#FB6964',
        '#342224',
        '#472E32',
        '#BDBB99',
        '#77B1A9',
        '#73A857'
      ];

    const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
    document.body.style = `background: ${color}`;

    return (
        <div className="Text-container" style={{color: color}}>
            <h3>Quotes</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><p>{textos.frase}</p></li> `<-- AQUI ESTA EL PROBLEMA`
                <li><p>{textos.autor}</p></li> `<-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM XD`
            </ul>
            <button onClick={changeText}>Next</button>
            <button onClick={() => window.location.reload()}>Refresh</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Text;
```

Este es mi archivo JSON el cual tiene las frases pero no las muestra en mi componente Text, la idea era hacer un botón que cada vez que haga click, cambie la frase con el autor correspondiente!

```
{
    "textos":  [
        {
            "frase": "Ganar lo es todo",
            "autor": "Ayanokoji"
        },
        {
            "frase": "El iq solo mide el razonamiento logico de las personas",
            "autor": "Alejandro Cullen"
        },
        {
            "frase": "Si crees que algo importa lo haras sin importar que",
            "autor": "Elon Musk"
        },
        {
            "frase": "Si puedes imaginarlo, puedes programarlo",
            "autor": "Difunto"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: La variable `texto` del useState donde la usas?

Comment: Dime si esto es lo que buscas? [enlace](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-waterfall-z4xnh3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Es lo que busco si, pero desde un archivo JSON, y que se muestren aleatoriamente por pantalla, tipo asi: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9cVgBm6Zus&ab_channel=OmarAleiserAlvarez

Comment: Ya recien la cambie para usarla en el <li><p>{texto.frase}</p></li>, pero nada, no se muestra la frase:(...

Comment: Mira mi respuesta a ver si te funciona

Comment: Hice un cambio en el json pero no es nada grande, funciona igual, quite `"textos":`

Comment: En tu enlace no visualiza las frases por pantalla en el <p>{frasess.frase}</p>, y lo que queria era que se visualizen

Comment: Entra de nuevo, hice unos cambios [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-waterfall-z4xnh3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: otra cosa es que esto `textos = JSON.stringify(textos)` no era necesario ahí estabas convirtiendo el objeto a un string por lo tanto no se iba a poder iterar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice algunos cambios en el archivo json ya que a como estaba hecho se me dificultaba acceder a la información.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import frases from "./textos.json";

const getRandom = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * frases.length);

export function App() {
  const [texto, setTexto] = useState(frases[getRandom()]);
  console.log(texto);//variable texto contiene el objeto random

  const changeText = () => {
    const random = getRandom();
    setTexto(frases[random]);//pasas el objeto random a texto con el setTexto()
  };

  const colors = [
    "#16a085",
    "#27ae60",
    "#2c3e50",
    "#f39c12",
    "#e74c3c",
    "#9b59b6",
    "#FB6964",
    "#342224",
    "#472E32",
    "#BDBB99",
    "#77B1A9",
    "#73A857"
  ];

  const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  document.body.style = `background: ${color}`;

      return (
        <div className="Text-container" style={{ color: "white" }}>
         {/* antes: style={{ color: color }} */}

          <h3>Quotes</h3>
             {/* 
                Usas texto que contiene el objeto y ingresas a los respectivos valores 
                Ejm de objeto que recibe:
                 {
                   frase: "El iq solo mide el razonamiento logico de las personas"
                   autor: "Alejandro Cullen"
                 }
             */}
             <ul>
               <li><p>{texto.frase}</p></li>
               <li><p>{texto.autor}</p></li> 
             </ul>

      <button onClick={changeText}>Next</button>
      <button onClick={() => window.location.reload()}>Refresh</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

En el Hook `const [texto, setTexto] = useState(frases[getRandom()]);` por lo que vi nunca usabas **texto** en ninguna parte y allí era donde se guardaba la data en cambio estabas imprimiendo **textos** con **S**

El color del texto `style={{ color: "white" }}` en `const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];` buscabas un color random pero estabas pasándole el mismo color tanto al background como al texto y por eso tampoco se veía ya que eran del mismo color.

***textos.json***

```
[
  {
    "frase": "Ganar lo es todo",
    "autor": "Ayanokoji"
  },
  {
    "frase": "El iq solo mide el razonamiento logico de las personas",
    "autor": "Alejandro Cullen"
  },
  {
    "frase": "Si crees que algo importa lo haras sin importar que",
    "autor": "Elon Musk"
  },
  {
    "frase": "Si puedes imaginarlo, puedes programarlo",
    "autor": "Difunto"
  }
]
```

***ANEXOS:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!, QUE CRACK <3

Comment: De nada, ya que le diste a respuesta correcta también dale a respuesta útil, la flechita hacia arriba.